# Neo4j: How to find distinct one-hop paths based on the weight of the relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

In this sample graph, I want a query that will select distinct one-hop paths when a pair of nodes have multiple one-hop relationships defined between the pair of nodes. I want to select the one-hop relation with the highest weight.

```
MATCH (x:FooNode) DETACH DELETE x RETURN COUNT(*);

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (x:FooNode)  ASSERT x.name IS UNIQUE;

CREATE (a:FooNode {name: 'a'}), (b:FooNode {name: 'b'}), (c:FooNode {name: 'c'}), 
       (d:FooNode {name: 'd'}), (e:FooNode {name: 'e'}), (f:FooNode {name: 'f'}),
  (a)-[:FooRelation1 {weight: 1}]->(b),
  (a)-[:FooRelation2 {weight: 2}]->(b),
  (a)-[:FooRelation3 {weight: 3}]->(b),
  (a)-[:FooRelation2 {weight: 2}]->(e),
  (a)-[:FooRelation4 {weight: 4}]->(e),
  (a)-[:FooRelation6 {weight: 6}]->(e),
  (e)-[:FooRelation1 {weight: 3}]->(c),
  (e)-[:FooRelation2 {weight: 1}]->(f),
  (c)-[:FooRelation3 {weight: 3}]->(d);

MATCH p = (s:FooNode) -[r]-> (t:FooNode) 
WITH DISTINCT {left: s.name, right: t.name} as Distincts
RETURN Distincts
```

For example, I want (a)-[:FooRelation3 {weight: 3}]->(b) to be returned but not (a)-[:FooRelation1 {weight: 1}]->(b), (a)-[:FooRelation2 {weight: 3}]->(b) based on the weight and all 3 are from (a) to (b).

Ideas?

**Update**

For some reason StackOverflow won't let me post this as an answer but it looks like I have found something that works. I still would appreciate your feedback.

```
MATCH p =  (n:FooNode)-[r]->(m:FooNode) 
WITH DISTINCT n, m, max(r.weight) AS maxw 
MATCH p2 = (n2)-[r2]->(m2) 
WHERE n2.name = n.name AND m2.name = m.name AND r2.weight = maxw 
RETURN p2, type(r2)
```

Technically, I just need to return p2.

CAUTION: Make sure auto-complete is OFF when you go to view the graph; else Neo4j will auto-display the related relationships (which will definitely throw you off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can improve on the query you found by reusing the variables for nodes and relationships that are already in scope.

```
MATCH (n:FooNode)-[r]->(m:FooNode) 
// no need for distinct since you're using the max() aggregation
WITH n, m, max(r.weight) AS maxw 
MATCH p = (n)-[r]->(m) 
WHERE r.weight = maxw 
RETURN p, type(r)
```

However, if there are multiple relationships with the same max weight, this will return all of those instead of just one.

Comment: Edited my answer to base it upon yours.

Comment: Good insight about relations with the same weight.  In my real scenario, they are distinct.  Thank you for pointing this out.  Your optimization on this small dataset substantially reduced the number of database hits from 1099 to 76.